# How NOT to display blank values in a table

Tags: powerbi, dax, powerbi-desktop

I have table dim_Territory that have a relationship with fact_Losses many to one.

If I throw `BusinessAutoTerrityfy` from `dim_Territory` and Measure `LossRatio` from table fact_losses then I see `blank` values.

I tried to use `ISBLANK()` value, `FILTERS` but nothing works.

How not to display blank values in this case?

[image]

[image]

[image]

Measure to calculate LossRatio:

```
Loss Ratio =
VAR LosRatio =
    IFERROR (
        IF (
            key_Measures[Selected Measure] <> [Total Claim Count w/o SubTot],
            DIVIDE ( key_Measures[Selected Measure], key_Measures[Total Earned] ),
            FORMAT ( 'Earned per Claim'[Earned per Incur Claim], "$#,##" )
        ),
        BLANK ()
    )
RETURN
    IF (
        NOT ( HASONEVALUE ( dim_Date[Year] ) ) && HASONEVALUE ( dim_Date[Month] ),
        BLANK (),
        LosRatio
    )
```

Comment: What the DAX for your `Loss Ratio` measure?

Comment: I updated. Its a little messy. sorry

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm guessing those "blank" rows are a result of the `FORMAT` branch of the logic and are actually empty strings `""` rather than true `BLANK()` values.

You can add a modification to the `RETURN` part convert those to a blank:

```
RETURN
    IF (
        NOT ( HASONEVALUE ( dim_Date[Year] ) ) && HASONEVALUE ( dim_Date[Month] ),
        BLANK(),
        IF( LosRatio = "", BLANK(), LosRatio )
    )
```

Comment: Oh! That is where was the problem!   Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

From PowerQuery Editor in Remove Rows you have the option to remove blank rows.

[Picture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Tv7Yv.png)